# Why we cannot have overloaded function signatures with optional parameters in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

According to [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) ([and corresponding example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAEFMCdoe2gZwFygEwFYDsGCwAoAMwFcA7AYwBcBLOU0AWwEMBrSAEScsgAoaHIiSkwYAHVKWIMARjACUqTtwDcBEhRp1GrDl14MJU2dAA0oACaGZMMwE8rxhaCWRVRMlVr1mbFzwYA8tAAKtQCQiLioJLWphYA-A42oLaJ0UbyinqgAN4EoKDUhKA85qAAhAC8laBk5pCE1KSQZQBkrSkV1bWk9Y3N5nK5%20QWg0JCUxND0zQDuzno8tmaBIWGCwmJmg24FAL6gkAA2iJDD%20KNjE1MzkPN%20q6Hhm6Jyu6B7BJ-45HRCFgBGUA1Hy6bg8AFoADMABYMAA2LAADjeBF%20pH%205jQwO0vkWGDMBNAGFRPz%20lAsUJxoL8ALMULeQA)) it's not possible. But I still cannot understand why 3rd function declaration doesn't match 3rd `makedate` call. Please, tell me what I don't understand? Thanks.

```js
// @errors: 2575
function makeDate(timestamp: number): Date;
function makeDate(m: number, d: number, y: number): Date;
function makeDate(mOrTimestamp: number, d?: number, y?: number): Date {
  if (d !== undefined && y !== undefined) {
    return new Date(y, mOrTimestamp, d);
  } else {
    return new Date(mOrTimestamp);
  }
}
const d1 = makeDate(12345678);
const d2 = makeDate(5, 5, 5);
const d3 = makeDate(1, 3); //No overload expects 2 arguments, but overloads do exist that expect either 1 or 3 arguments.
```

Comment: That "third function declaration" is the implementation signature, not another call signature

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature

Comment: Do you mean it's enough to make a call signature with optional parameters to match the third function call? @jcalz . Yep, looks like that, thanks for the link

Comment: Yes, have you tried it? ... but why would you *want* to do that?  The implementation will just drop the `3` because it's only expecting the two original call signatures

Comment: I am inclined to close this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68213949/overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature-in-typescript unless you [edit] the question demonstrating that you already understand the difference between call signatures and implementation signature

Comment: @jcalz Ok I understand, and I will. Should I post it like an answer?

Comment: Sure, if you want to post your own answer that's fine

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly artificial example, which destroys the confusion. Let's assume `makeDate` **with two parameters** accepts month and year and still makes a `new Date`.

```js
// @errors: 2575
function makeDate(timestamp: number): Date;
function makeDate(m: number, d: number, y: number): Date;
function makeDate(m: number, y: number): Date;
function makeDate(mOrTimestamp: number, d?:number, y?:number) {
  if (d !== undefined && y !== undefined) {
    return new Date(y, mOrTimestamp, d);
  } else if (d !== undefined && y === undefined) {
    return new Date(mOrTimestamp, d);
  } else {
    return new Date(mOrTimestamp);
  }
}
const d1 = makeDate(12345678);
const d2 = makeDate(5, 5, 5);
const d3 = makeDate(1, 3);
```

The same example on the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAEFMCdoe2gZwFygEwFYDsGCwAoAMwFcA7AYwBcBLOU0AWwEMBrSAEScsgAoaHIiSkwYAHVKWIMARjACUqTtwDcBEhRp1GrDl14MJU2dAA0oACaGZMMwE8rxhaCWRVRMlVr1mbFzwOgktamoPaBRvKKem7qnlo%20utz%20APLQACrUAkIi4uHBZuYA-MhBxnbFpfKgAN4EoKDUhKA85qAAhAC8HaBk5pCE1KSQrQBkI6HtXT2kfQND5nI1dfWg0JCUxND0QwDuzno8tmYMqRlZwmIFcm71AL6gkAA2iJANTS2T3b39g8OgYxMul8Zj95otavgVqt1pttpA9n4TulMoILqIrjdQPcni8lpCVmsNltAvD9kkkWdUTlrstbgQ6fhyHQhBYAIygboJPystAAZgALBgAGxYAAcNMZzMoFjQHO0vgOGDMStAGAlTNILPMvLlXIOrLMvOuQA). The key for me was distinguishing that
*the call signature and the implementation signature are different entities*.

Comment: thanks to @jcalz for the clarification